# Extract Name out of Log ( Regex, If/else)

Tags: regex, logging

i have different log entry in my logfile and want to extract the hostname

my current regex looks like: `\[[^:]*` (but does not work very well)

What i want:

```
hostA
hostB
hostC
hostD
```

Log Example

```
Dec 22 12:15:40 0.0.0.0 [hostA: some.text]: 
Dec 22 12:15:40 0.0.0.0 [loremipsumdolor@hostB: some.text]:
Dec 22 12:15:40 0.0.0.0 [hostC: some.text]:
Dec 22 12:15:40 0.0.0.0 [sometext@hostD: some.text]:
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want the output to be literally `HOSTNAME`?

Comment: Yes, i need only the hostname in the line... but sometimes der is a random text and a @ in front of the hostname...

Comment: You want [this](https://regex101.com/r/hR3mC2/1)?

Comment: Sorry, the `HOSTNAME` is variable...

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either

```
\[([^\]@]*@)?(?P<host>.*?):
```

to capture the host name in the named group `host`. ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR3mC2/2))

or

```
(?<=[\[@])[^@]*?(?=:)
```

to match only the host name. ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR3mC2/3))

The first pattern matches text after the first `[` character, skipping everything up to the next `@` if it exists.

The second pattern will pick up anything between a `[` or `@` and a `:`, so it's a little more likely to produce false positives I think.